# Disable auto-focus on input field for alert controller ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

How do I disable the created alert using alert controller from automatically focusing onto the input field with the keyboard being displayed?

```
let alert = self.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Login',
        inputs: [
          {
            name: 'location_code',
            placeholder: 'Location Code',
          },
          {
            name: 'password',
            placeholder: 'Password',
            type: 'password'
          }
        ],
        buttons: [
          {
            text: 'Cancel',
            role: 'cancel',
            handler: data => {
              console.log('Cancel clicked');
            }
          },
          {
            text: 'Login',
            handler: data => {
                 console.log("Handling Login On Click")
              });
            }
          }
        ]
      });
      alert.present();
```

Attempted Solution which didn't result in any change

```
this.alertController.create(
...
)
.present({
    keyboardClose: true
});
```

Comment: I guess this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47581533/18799650) might be helpful for you

Comment: @g78 what is the syntax for ionic code though?

Answer (score 0):

In ionic 3 there was no *keyboardClose* option (see [v3](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v3/blob/2b7292e8a1187351fff9629bcef271d277abb318/src/components/alert/alert-options.ts#L2) vs [v5](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/9fbaaf95eb65ebf034b8b54ccbee58b4634f5c3c/core/src/components/alert/alert-interface.ts#L4)), so you probably need to manually remove focus, eg like this:

```
let alert = self.alertCtrl.create({...});
alert.present().then(() => {
  (<any>document.querySelector('ion-alert input')).blur();
})
```